# How to run multiple java projects on single ec2 instance

Tags: java, maven, amazon-ec2

I have a java project that runs on `EC2`. Now I want to run another maven project on that EC2 instance(its not a web app). How to do that? Will this affect my already running project?

Comment: You can deploy multiple wars in tomcat ,or you can deploy multiple docker containers with java app or you can run the jars if they have different ports  by creating systemd services.And it wont affect your existing app if you have enough memory (RAM) to run all apps and if you have different ports for every application